# how to get length of queue in AODV?

Tags: ns2

I try to get `length of queue in MAC layer into aodv protocol by ns2` but when I recall `if queue->length()` function , got `"Segmentation Fault"`.

I searched how to get length of queue in MAC layer and got the cause of it is returned zero value every time.

unfortunately I didn't find any correct answer to solve it !
I did following steps :

```
 in AODV::recvHello(Packet *p){
 ....
 double length;
 length=ifqueue->length();
 ...
 }
```

but when I run the simulation file for wireless , got segmentation fault(core dumped) in output!

I try to recall it every where of AODV but I got same error!

could you please guide me where i am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it finally.
when Length() function defined as protected this error shown.
so I define it as public and this problem solved :)

but for solving any error on tcl you can use following command :

```
valgrid --track-check=yes ns filename.tcl
```

after running this command you can see position and cause of errors.
I used it to find cause of my problem and saw "memory stack". this means the program can't access to memory for protected function!